# UIWebview not showing editview on first tap

Tags: ios, uiwebview, touch, tap, editview

This is an issue with iOS9 and later.

On the load of application I select a word in UIWebview but theres no editview popup showing copy, share, define etc options on first tap.
From next selection after the tap it works fine.

even the -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender delegate returns NO for all options on first tap and select

Also when you select a word and scroll it up off the screen and try to select other word. the view scrolls up/down on its own and a worng word will be selected(View displaces itself by an offset of the amount the selected word is scrolled off the screen).

Pulling my hair to get this fixed. Any help would be appreciated
 its simple code

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


[self.view becomeFirstResponder];
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

}

Comment: Do you have code or something that you can show us that isn't working? It's hard to know what is broken if we don't know what it is.

Comment: Edit your question to include that.

Comment: Did it @Dow Its very simple Just added web view and loaded wikipedia.
I think the problem is with iOS 9. It works well with iOS 8

Comment: I'm not an IOS developer unfortunately. I just noticed the question in the review queue and I'm just trying help you make it solvable for someone else.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebview has many bugs and is not memory efficient .
Replaced UIWebview with WKWebView on apple's recommendation and it fixed all the bugs.